# Changing opacity to a particular value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a navigation bar which becomes visible slowly as the user scrolls through it in larger screens.
I don't want the opacity to become completely

1. I want the navigation bar to be a little transparent atleast and the font within it to have opacity value 1.
2. How can I do it? This below code makes the opacity of the navigation bar completely 1 on scroll action.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top"); 
        $('.navbar').css('opacity', 1)
    } else {
        $('.navbar').css('opacity', 0)
    }
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 480) 
        $('.navbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 900));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want just background little bit transparent then use background-color: rgba(); .. it will give opacity to background only. otherwise giving opacity to whole wrapper will apply on children too weather you give opacity to children 1.

Comment: :D. Thankyou.
I did it using your principle but used a color code instead of rgba.
`$('.navbar').css("background-color","#ffffdf");`